# How to print a FORM?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, printing

I have a form which I need to print with its CSS and the data that the user has registered in it. Could you help me?

HTML:

Here is my form

CSS:

```
@media print {
  .container-fluid {width: auto}
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;

    
  } 
  #imprimir, #imprimir * {
    visibility: visible;

    
    
  }
  #imprimir {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

This works, but it prints me two blank sheets, along with my form..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Extra space may have came from body with visibility hidden, it preserve element space in css, use display: none instead.

```
@media print {
  .container-fluid {width: auto}
  body * {
    display: none;

    
  } 
  #imprimir, #imprimir * {
    display: block !important;
    
  }
  #imprimir {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have changed it and when printing it only generates a blank page

Comment: I added `!important` try now.